# How can I install opencv python or C++ in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

It is different how to install opencv in Python and C++. right? So I have a question. as you saw my title, How can I use Opencv to Python and C++? It means Can I coding Opencv with both of them in Ubuntu? I'm poor at english. So if you don't understand my question, please comment me. thank you

Comment: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: this is easily googleable... you don't need to ask this on SO.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV.   This is too vague you don't appear to have attempted this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Just run this [script](https://github.com/milq/milq/blob/master/scripts/bash/install-opencv.sh), sit back and relax. This will install OpenCV on your system for C++, Python, and Java.

Comment: Getting error: Failed to find "GL/gl.h" in "/usr/include/libdrm".

Answer (score 0):

Install openCV:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

Usage in python:

```
# import openCV package
import cv2
# ...... use it
```

For further information, go to the official page.[ [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) ]

Comment: _The python-opencv repository is older, outdated, and doesn’t include the opencv_contrib package. I cannot say this enough - I do not recommend installing OpenCV via apt-get. You’ll be missing features and be running an older, outdated version._ Quote from Adrian Rosebrock of PyImageSearch: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/ --- note that the official documentation does not suggest to use the `python-opencv` repository.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced to install python opencv on my PC more than 10 times. And I can provide the best way to install Python OpenCV (as per my knowledge) on Ubuntu.

Collecting all the terminal commands and executing them in the expected is not simple, and for beginners it's a lot of heck.

Download the below .sh file from github :
[Github Link for the File](https://github.com/AnanthReddyGit/Install-Python-OpenCV)

And execute the file on terminal by the following commands. Make sure to change the directory to the location of .sh file

```
    chmod +x execute.sh
    ./execute.sh
```

And that's all after the installation check the presence of OpenCV by the following command in python IDLE

```
    import cv2
```

Thank You. Hope you got it.